# Facebook app form android approval

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-apps

I have created an app for android and iOS and I'm having problems in testing this app's because is not public approved app. I need to test the app before publishing app's in store but google play images are necessary for approval. This is the scenario:
I need Facebook app aproval before publish app
I need app is published before facebook app approval

How could I continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Go to Facebook and chose Developer option in facebook then go to status & Review then you will see "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" and Right side button Display which you should "on" called "Yes" then your app will publicly access or approved by Facebook....

[Go To Link](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/1403097239989092/review-status/)